# Nervous Cursor on 2013 MacBook Pro 15" Retina

Tags: macbook-pro, cursor

While I try to get some writing done on my MacBook Pro 15" Retina (first under Mountain Lion and now Mavericks) the cursor will often jump randomly away from where I'm typing to another location in the text. Read somewhere that switching off BlueTooth would help prevent these annoying twitches, but that simply does not seem true: the cursor still jumps unexpectedly especially at higher touch-typing speeds. Is there a known cure for this flaw? It sure plays havoc with productivity. Grrr.

Comment: Have you taken the laptop to a repair depot or Apple Store? It sounds like you might have a problem with the trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

Does it jump around randomly everywhere, both desktop and applications, or is it only when you type? Mine jumped around everywhere several times, but every time it stopped after I cleaned the trackpad thoroughly. Also dust can get trapped at the border, so push down and clean as good as you can (beware of using too much water of course).

Comment: Only when I type, and only inside the text already written.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is due to accidental input from the touchpad.  Apple does try to limit the problem, but for me it has become a bigger problem with the new bigger touchpad.  The solution I have uses the betterTouchTool app.  I have set up a key - actually on the toucher - which hits the following sequence of key presses: ^z^z^Z where ^ means control.  So it does two undos followed by a redo which puts the cursor back where you were before it jumped elsewhere (usually in the document.  It is still a nuisance - who among us doesn't drop their wrists a bit while typing, even though doing so is bad form?  Professional typists perhaps are good.